# Which fields are required for auth0.webAuth.authorize()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, auth0

I'm using react-native-auth0 version 1.6.0, and have been following the guide on the [Github page here](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0). In the "Web Authentication" -> "Log In" sections, it recommends passing only `scope` and `audience` to the `auth0.webAuth.authorize()` method. However, I also saw [this documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#database-ad-ldap-passive-) where in the "Database/AD/LDAP" section they say that `response_type`, `client_id`, and `redirect_uri` are all required.

**What I Want To Know:**

What is the difference between the protocols followed for `auth0.webAuth.authorize()` in the [first](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0) and [second](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#database-ad-ldap-passive-) guides? Which should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the params are assumed because of the library or already input when you initialize. For instance, response type is assumed to be `code`, and you will have already input your client ID when initializing WebAuth.

https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#authorization-code-flow-with-pkce